# Libgdx + Facebook Integration?

Tags: facebook, libgdx, integration

Anyone has succeeded in this? Do you use the Facebook Official SDK and make a interface in the Android folder of the Project, or how can we do this?

Answer (score 4):

Yes and yes.  Use an interface to access platform specific code (Android Facebook SDK in this case).  See https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code.